# WPRIG: postCSS not recognizing nested CSS (using

Tags: css, postcss

I've just started using wp-rig v2.0.1 and postCSS doesn't seem to recognize &-nested CSS. I get an error saying that the curlybrace after .test is unexpected.

```
.wp-block-group {
    background:red;
    .test { 
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Wprig comes with postcss-preset-env installed.

Answer (score 0):

my experience with wp-rig is that you need the ampersand prefix to all nested rules, as in:

```
.wp-block-group {
    background:red;
    &.test { 
        background: red;
    }
}
```